# Spring 4.1.1 and google ehcache annotation 1.2.0 compatibility

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

Is Spring 4.1.1 and google ehcache annotation 1.2.0 compatibile because I am getting following exception while deploying the war on Jboss:

> 2014-11-12 09:42:29,721 ERROR
>   [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread
>   Pool -- 1071) Context initialization failed:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParserConfiguration.(Lorg/springframework/expression/spel/SpelCompilerMode;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:98)
>   [spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
>   [spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:455)
>   [spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>   [spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>   [spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>   [spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]     at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

When searched I found that ehcache version 1.2.0 requires spring 3.0.6.

Is there any way apart from downgrading the spring version to make it work ?

Comment: Don't use it use Springs `@Cacheable` annotation instead. The google-ehcache annotations are old and not maintained anymore (afaik). Spring 4.1 also supports the new JDK caching API so you could use the standard annotations as well (tying you to no framework code wise).

Comment: How can I implement self populating cache using the spring's ehcache annotations ?

Comment: A self populating cache has nothing to do with the annotations imho but just with how you configure eh-cache (and you can use some bootstrapping code to do that for you).

Comment: Can you provide any example or any poc link where in self populating cache is implemented.